# Create a collection inside users document: Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an "Orders" collection inside the user document so that I can be able to get the orders that a specific user has made. This is what I tried:

```
if(firebaseUser!=null){
    String userID= firebaseUser.getUid();
    DocumentReference userDoc= db.collection("users").document(userID);
    userDoc.collection("orders").document(model.getMeal_name() + " " + day)
            .set(order).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Order entry into database");
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

But it's creating the document in the users collection as opposed to creating it inside a document. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my database screenshot with the new document it created.

[image]

Comment: As I see, there is a sub-collection called `orders`. Wasn't the document added there?

Comment: Oooh yeah... It had been created but with a different ID because it wasn't matching my authentication ID.

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for?